# How to print multiple lines in C

Tags: python, c, range, tuples

I have a piece of Python code that reads as follow:

```
template = \
"""
                 %2s  %2s  %2s

                 %2s   R  %2s

                 %2s  %2s  %2s

    %2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s    %2s  %2s  %2s

    %2s   B  %2s   %2s   W  %2s   %2s   G  %2s    %2s   Y  %2s

    %2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s    %2s  %2s  %2s

                 %2s  %2s  %2s

                 %2s   O  %2s

                 %2s  %2s  %2s
    """

print template % tuple(range(1, 49))
```

I am trying to convert the code above into C (Yes I just started learning, it's probably quite self-evident) and, for the life of me, cannot find any documentation that could help me here.

I have already tried using Cython, but ended up with ridiculously long code that is, for me, not practical to implement in my program. I have also searched Stackoverflow for quite some time, to no avail. If I have missed something, please send me a link.

Comment: In your SO search, did you come across the page [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Also, consider reading the [About SO page](http://stackoverflow.com/about), as your status suggests you did not do so.

Comment: I did, but admittedly don't understand what is wrong with my question, except maybe its length.

Comment: As new posters to SO go, this question is much better than many. To print in C one usually uses `printf` or some variant. It looks like the format for printf and python may be compatible for your use (I don't do python, but "%2s" is for a string that will expand to be at least 2 characters), but from your context it looks like you can give python's print a way to enumerate the variable arguments automatically; C doesn't give you that.

Comment: In other words, it's impossible? I certainly am aware of the printf() function. It's pretty much the formatting and the tuple argument that's giving me trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a portable way to generate argument list, so i can't think of any simple solution better than typing the whole list like printf(template, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 49).

Another solution would be to manually go through the template and do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_template_with_range(char *template, int start, int end) {
  int i = 1;
  char *str = strdup(template);
  char *cur = str;
  char *pos;
  while ((pos = strstr(cur, "%2s")) != NULL) {
    *pos = '\0';
    printf("%s", cur);
    printf("%2d", i++);
    cur = pos + 3;
  }
  printf("%s", cur);
  free(str);
}

int main() {
char* format_string = "\n\
             %2s  %2s  %2s\n\
\n\
             %2s   R  %2s\n\
\n\
             %2s  %2s  %2s\n\
\n\
%2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s    %2s  %2s  %2s\n\
\n\
%2s   B  %2s   %2s   W  %2s   %2s   G  %2s    %2s   Y  %2s\n\
\n\
%2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s    %2s  %2s  %2s\n\
\n\
             %2s  %2s  %2s\n\
\n\
             %2s   O  %2s\n\
\n\
             %2s  %2s  %2s\n\
    ";
print_template_with_range(format_string, 1, 49);
return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
              1   2   3

              4   R   5

              6   7   8

 9  10  11   12  13  14   15  16  17    18  19  20

21   B  22   23   W  24   25   G  26    27   Y  28

29  30  31   32  33  34   35  36  37    38  39  40

             41  42  43

             44   O  45

             46  47  48
```

Comment: In VS2012 this compiles perfectly, but crashed at runtime. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Upon running in debug mode, the following error pops up: Unhandled exception at 0x000614B2 in Template.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00065876.

Comment: I was doing something stupid: writing into the constant template. I have edited to code to copy it first.

Comment: Note: you could use `("\n"  "             %2s  %2s  %2s\n");` instead of backslashes. Compiler concatenates the string literals into one.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can throw a collection at a string and magic happens.  That's the joy of a high-level language.

C is not joyful or a high-level language.

You're going to have to make an array with the data you want to print and then loop over printf and/or puts calls to emit the output you want (either line-by-line, char-by-char, or a mix).

To do something similar to what you're doing above:

```
char* format_string = " \
             %2s  %2s  %2s \
\
             %2s   R  %2s \
\
             %2s  %2s  %2s \
\
%2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s    %2s  %2s  %2s \
\
%2s   B  %2s   %2s   W  %2s   %2s   G  %2s    %2s   Y  %2s \
\
%2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s   %2s  %2s  %2s    %2s  %2s  %2s \
\
             %2s  %2s  %2s \
\
             %2s   O  %2s \
\
             %2s  %2s  %2s \
    ";

printf(format_string, t[0], t[1], ...);
```

Comment: I have a problem with this though: I don't seem to be able putting the starting and ending quotation marks on separate lines. Am I doing something wrong or is it your code?

Comment: You need to add \n\n at the end of lines

Comment: Or escape the end of each line with a backslash.  I'll update it.